# Is there a way to add configuration files to one maven project and share them in other maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, configuration-files

I would like to add some common configuration files like checkstyle rules, findbug rules, PMD rules etc., to one maven project and refer to these files in other maven projects.

Is there a way this can be done in Maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4j configuration file in a multi-module Maven project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162992/log4j-configuration-file-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)

Comment: The easiest way would be, to put the plugins and its resources into your parent pom?

Comment: For checkstyle rules there is an [example in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html). In [findbugs-maven-plugin there is also an example in the docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html). PMD might be the way via maven-remote-resource-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Maven Remote Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) plugin.

Example [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/examples/sharing-resources.html).